# iphone - easy way to have that press -> delete effects? or move -> relocate view effect?

Tags: iphone, uiview, shake

On iphone's home, you can press and hold on one app for 2 secs, then everyone is shaking and waiting to be delete or relocate.

How can I have this in my own view?

1. press & hold on somewhere and every subview is shaking
2. press & hold on somewhere so user can relocate the views?

Just like iOs's home screen or ibook or quite many other apps?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) You'd have to use UILongPressGestureRecognizer to detect long presses

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(startWobbling)];
[anyView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
[longPressGesture release];
```

and then in the startWobbling selector do:

```
CGAffineTransform leftWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(-5.0));
CGAffineTransform rightWobble = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, RADIANS(5.0));


view.transform = leftWobble;  // starting point

[UIView beginAnimations:@"wobble" context:view];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES]; // important
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(wobbleEnded:finished:context:)];

btn.transform = rightWobble; // end here & auto-reverse

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

2) Refer Touches sample code from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: thanks, Vin, so u mean there is no direct SpringBoard thing for me to use?

Comment: I don't think SpringBoard is directly available without using private apis.

Comment: A note for noob iOS developers (like me!).  This example assume a selector method signature without parameters.  If using a selector signature such as the following:

`- (void) startWobbling:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {}`

you will need to modify the selector declaration to include a colon.

Change from this:
`@selector(startWobbling)`

to this:
`@selector(startWobbling:)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TTLauncher view from the Three20 lib. It is pretty easy to customize and gives you all the wobbling and relocating you are looking for: http://three20.info/showcase/launcher